# How do I drop an edge when I know the parent and child vertices?

Tags: database, graph, gremlin, edges, vertices

I would like to do a drop() in an edge but the information I have is the parent and the child vertices.

What makes me sense is something like this:

`g.E().outV('123').inV('456').drop()`

or

`g.E().has('outV', '123').has('inV', '456').drop()`

but it doesn't seem to work.
I know another way to do this query but it would be in several queries and I want to do it in a single one. On the Internet, I found nothing that could help me.^
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the edge from the parent and drop it:

```
g.V('123').outE().where(inV().hasId('456')).drop()
```

this query will drop any edge between vertex '123' to vertex '456'.